# SQL - find usercode based on latest timestamp

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that look like this:

[image: Table]

I would like to make a query that creates another table called "LastUser" which shows the USER that has the last TIME. In the example above that would be record 2 - 053527/dlmk.

It should look something like this:

```
TIME     USER   LASTUSER
083527   dph    dlmk
084119   dlmk   dlmk
083527   dph    dlmk
074747   dph    dlmk
```

Any suggestion how I can do this?

Comment: What happens when the day changes?

Comment: why do you need to create another table? or you just want to show data from different tables?

Comment: If you are just after showing the data, I do recommend you to create a view if it is something that you are going to use quite often

Comment: @Larnu That not an issue in this case.

Comment: @Iria This query is actually used for a print label. I just wanted another table so i could show the "lastuser" on the label.

Comment: I would create a view instead, and then do it, a view avoids data duplication

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`first_value()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/first-value-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) for this:

```
select t.*,
       first_value(user) over (order by time desc) as last_user
from t;
```

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what i was looking for